# How to set a polkit rule to lock shutdown if a file exists?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-device-driver, polkit

I'm writing an application to control the system shutdown if a pendrive is connected to the system.

When pendrive is connected, It writes its identifier in a file. If pendrive is disconnected, it remove its identifier of the file and, after this, if  the file is empty, remove the file.

Then, I want to set a  polkit rule to control the shutdown, using this file.
The polkit rule detect the shutdown order and check if the file exists. If it exists, don't allow the shutdown, else allow it.

I try to set it as this form:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop") ||
        action.id.indexOf("org.freedesktop.login1.power-off") == 0) 
    {

        try{    
            polkit.spawn(["/usr/bin/detect_pendrive.sh", subject.user]);        
            return polkit.Result.YES;

        }catch(error){
            return polkit.Result.NO;
        }
    }
});
```

The polkit rule use a helper, with a script that check the existence os the file

The detect_pendrive.sh is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! test -e "/tmp/usbdevinfo" 
then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

I copy the rule in /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/. But, when I try to shutdown with a pendrive connected, the system simply poweroff and ignore the rule.

I tested it on Debian GNOME and Gentoo Cinnamon

Where can be the problem?

Comment: Just a tip, stackoverflow only support vanilla markdown, not the advanced one you are used to, in vanilla markdown, you can only mark a codeblock using spaces, and using ` doesn't make an easy to read one

Comment: Can you check which version of ubuntu you're running on? I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536591/policykit-rules-never-come-into-effect) on another site from the stackexchange-network.

Comment: I'm not using Ubuntu. I test this rule in Gentoo and Debian, unsuccessfull

Comment: In my system, I checked and I have polkit .rules files, so It isn't the problem

Comment: Post your answer as an answer (it's fine to answer your own question). Don't edit it into your question.

Comment: @Mat Other people said me the inverse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

As @ferrybig previosly said, polkit rules don't runs in polkit < 0.106

Then, I solved this with a dual policy:

If polkit < 0.106, I created this .pkla file

```
[Shutdown]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions;org.xfce.session.xfsm-shutdown-helper
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=no
```

To solve the problem, I use the same scripts linked to two udev rules to add and remove the rule. This scripts, furthermore to create and remove the file, add the .pkla file during the pendrive connection and, during the disconnection, if the file is empty, also remove .pkla file

In polkit >= 0.106, I simply use the initial rules file, adding a new action:

`action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions"`

The rules file will be as this:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
 if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop" ||
    action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off" ||
    action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions" || 
    action.id == "org.xfce.session.xfsm-shutdown-helper")  
 {

    try{    
        polkit.spawn(["/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/check_pendrive.sh", subject.user]);        
        return polkit.Result.YES;

    }catch(error){
        polkit.spawn(["/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/send_notify.sh", subject.user]);
        return polkit.Result.NO;
    }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your polkit.rule is ok on my OpenBSD 6.2 GENERIC.MP#134 amd64

I don't use consolekit but org.xfce.session.policy

My rule file :

```
polkit.addRule (function (action, subject) {
  if (action.id == "org.xfce.session.xfsm-shutdown-helper") {
    try {
      polkit.spawn(["/home/alain/polkitspawn.sh",subject.user]);
        return polkit.Result.YES; 
    }
    catch (error) {
      return "no";
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok. Then I'll search other session policy

Comment: What service can be suppling to consolekit?